# how to start tomcat server automatically through tomcat 7 maven plugin

Tags: maven, tomcat7-maven-plugin

How to start a tomcat server which is present in my local through tomcat7 maven plugin...how to give the source of my local tomcat server in tomcat plugin so that if we give the tomcat7:run command...local server will run automcatically.

Answer (score 0):

You must provide the `url` in the plugin configuration.
Note that for Tomcat 8 instances (I havent tested it in earlier tomcat versions) you need `domain:port/manager/text`

```
     <plugins>
        .. 
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/text</url>
                <path>/examplePath</path>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        ..
      </plugins>
```

Comment: i have given the same. for this i need to start the tomcat server manually.....i don't want to do like that.....i want to start the remote server and deploy the war through this maven configuration only.....i have also mentioned <executions>
      <execution>
       <id>tomcat-run</id>
       <goals>
        <goal>run-war-only</goal>
       </goals>
       <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
      </execution>
     </executions>